# Recover connection when using Spring JMSTemplate and ApacheMQ

Tags: spring, jms

**//OVERVIEW//**

I have a Java Swing Client that is pushing messages to a broker. For the producer,  I am using the Spring SingleConnectionFactory:

`org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory`

that is wrapped around an ActiveMQConnectionFactory:

`org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`

I am using the Spring JMSTemplate:

```
org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate
```

to provide the mechanisms to send messages from the producer to the broker.

**// PROBLEM //**

Sometimes, the broker might go down, or the network might fail. When this happens, the only way I have been able to re-establish connection to the broker is to re-start the Swing application (producer) to re-initialize the components mentioned above.

Does anyone know how this might be done at run-time? Atempting to re-initialise beans at runtime sounds like a hack and I was wondering if there was a more elegant configuration option.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered [setReconnectOnException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory.html#setReconnectOnException%28boolean%29)?

Comment: Brilliant. That has worked. Thank you